# How to specify file size using repartition() in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet, partitioning

Im using pyspark and I have a large data source that I want to repartition specifying the files size per partition explicitly.

I know using the `repartition(500)` function will split my parquet into 500 files with almost equal sizes.
The problem is that new data gets added to this data source every day. On some days there might be a large input, and on some days there might be smaller inputs. So when looking at the partition file size distribution over a period of time, it varies between `200KB` to `700KB` per file.

I was thinking of specifying the **max size** per partition so that I get more or less the same file size per file per day irrespective of the number of files.
This will help me when running my job on this large dataset later on to avoid skewed executor times and shuffle times etc.

Is there a way to specify it using the `repartition()` function or while writing the dataframe to parquet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could consider writing your result with the parameter `maxRecordsPerFile`.

```py
storage_location = //...
estimated_records_with_desired_size = 2000
result_df.write.option(
     "maxRecordsPerFile", 
     estimated_records_with_desired_size) \
     .parquet(storage_location, compression="snappy")
```

Comment: But to do that, I first need to find out how many records there are in a 100MB file and `then set the maxRecordsPerFile` to that correct?
Is there no way to directly specify max size of the file?

Comment: Your understanding is correct. And a direct answer to your question, no, currently no. 
A DataFrame in memory needs to be encoded and compressed before being written to a disk (or object-storage location such as AWS S3), and the default persistent mode is `StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK`.
Briefly saying, until the outcome is fully written to the disk, there is no way to estimate the actual size of files during the writing.

Comment: Understood. If so, How would I go about finding the number of rows for only 100MB of data?

Comment: Assume your data structure in a row is consistent and you have a file of 1,000 records (the outcome). With the precondition, you can get the average size of a row for your outcome. Say the average size is 100kb, then the estimated rows for 100 MB will be (100 x 1,024) / 100 = 1024 (rows).
Compressed or not, `.csv` or `.parquet`, the progress will be similar. This is the quickest way to fulfill your requirement or desire. Within the compression scenario (`file_name.csv.gz`), there might be a math formula but it'll take a bit more time than the previous method I provide.

Comment: Thank you. I was asking so that I can estimate the number of rows that will go into a partition when I try to use your method in the answer. 
How do you find the size of a record? I tried using `getByte(df.head())` suggested in one of the answers in this forum but it dint work for pyspark.

Comment: Say, you have written out an outcome by `.repartition(8)`. Grasp one of the 8 files, assume there are 5 columns in your outcome and they are fixed, i.e., not matter how many partitions (files) are generated, there will always be 5 columns.
With this situation, you can get the average size of a 5-column row, then you can temporarily determine a rough number for `maxRecordsPerFile`.
The core idea is to get the distribution of data as close as the population of your outcome.

Comment: Ah, so you mean to literally load a single snappy partition in a dataframe, count the number of rows and divide the size of that snappy partition file by the number of rows to get avg size of one row. That makes sense now. Thank you!

Comment: @Scott Hsieh
 How you are getting average size of rows in dataframe?